# How can I acquire Daedric weapons In Skyrim without a high smithing skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to collect 1 of every weapon in skyrim and right now I'm focusing on Daedric weapons, but since I don't have a high smithing skill (I don't consider it to be an important skill) I'm not able to craft them myself.

What level do you have to be to see them in merchants inventories to buy or to be able to find them?  Are there any locations where I might find some Daedric weapons or armour?

Comment: Why isn't smithing important? You can vastly improve both weapon damage and armor rating with a high smithing level.

Comment: IDK I just really never thought it was that important but I guess I could start because I've completed almost every quest line.( main quests, dark brotherhood, thieves guild, companions) so I have alot of time to do whatever I want.

Answer (score 3):

According to [UESP](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric#Daedric_Weapons), you need to be level 46 to start seeing random Daedric weapons.

However, if you want to get Daedric weapons faster, I would recommend that you get the Daedric Smithing perk. The main ingredients for Daedric weapons are Ebony Ingots and Daedric hearts.

[Ebony ingots](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ebony_Ingot#Overview) are available as early as level 13, but can be purchased at general stores and blacksmiths at level 27. Additionally, you can get them sooner from the Ebony mine.

[Daedric Hearts](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedra_Heart) are going to be harder to find, but are a guaranteed drop from [Dremora](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dremora). They are also a rare ingredient, and as such can be purchased from apothecaries.

Comment: If Kaleb has completed "Pieces of the Past", he will have four guaranteed dremoras at Mehrunes Dagon's shrine (2 outside and 2 inside), as well as a couple of ebony ingots inside.  This is repeatable, you just have to let the area respawn.

Comment: I've done this quite a few times myself (Mehrunes Dagon). IIRC they also usually carry Daedric Greataxes/WarAxes

Answer (score 0):

- Deadric weapons require a smithing level of 90.
- they appear at level 46
- It seems the easiest way to get daedric items at your level is from smithing them, once you wear them they will become available form merchants

I haven't played for a while so I don't know if this is still possible, but the easiest way to level up your smithing is to just make a bunch of iron daggers. I did this and levelled my smithing ridiculously fast

Comment: Smithing is now advanced based on the value of the item you are crafting. So, iron daggers is a really slow way to go. The best way to level Smithing is to craft jewelry.

Comment: @ChargingPun ahhh okay, shows how long its been since I played!